# C++ printing out bool type variables

Tags: c++

Hy there, I'm new at C++ and I have small problem. There is a function called "bool checkIfPersonAlreadyExists () {...} " and I want that this function return a bool type variable, but it doesn't. Can anyone help me with this? (The answer should be "true" or "false" but in this kind of form: "return IfPersonAlreadyExists").

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Library {
    private:
        string name, surname;
        int LSP;
        bool IfPersonAlreadyExists;

        //toString metodas ir kaip ji pasiekti is private?????
        string toString (string name) {
            cout << name << " " << surname << " " << LSP << endl;
            return name;
        }
    public:
        //setters
        int setName (string name) {
            if (!name.empty() && isalpha(name[0]) && isupper(name[0]))
               this -> name = name;
            else {
                cout << "Wrong entry!" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        int setSurname (string surname) {
            if (!surname.empty() && isalpha(surname[0]) && isupper(surname[0]))
                this -> surname = surname;
            else {
                cout << "wrong entry!" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        int setLSP (int LSP) {
            if (LSP > 0)
                this -> LSP = LSP;
            else {
                cout << "Wrong entry!" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        void setIfPersonAlreadyExists (bool IfPersonAlreadyExists) {
            this -> IfPersonAlreadyExists = IfPersonAlreadyExists;
            IfPersonAlreadyExists = true;
        }
        //getters
        string getName () {
            return name;
        }
        string getSurname () {
            return surname;
        }
        int getLSP () {
            return LSP;
        }
        bool getIfPersonAlreadyExists () {
            return IfPersonAlreadyExists;
        }

        //Kaip padaryti kad return true or false?????/?
        bool checkIfPersonAlreadyExists (bool IfPersonAlreadyExists, int LSP) {
            int LSPCheck;
            cout << "Enter LSP number to check" << endl;
            cin >> LSPCheck;
            if (LSPCheck != LSP) {
                IfPersonAlreadyExists = false;
                //cout << boolalpha << IfPersonAlreadyExists << endl;
                return IfPersonAlreadyExists;
            }
            else {
                IfPersonAlreadyExists = true;
                cout << boolalpha << IfPersonAlreadyExists << endl;
                return IfPersonAlreadyExists;
            }
        }
};


int main () {
    Library library;
    string name, surname;
    int LSP;
    bool IfPersonAlreadyExists = true;
    cout << "Enter your name: " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    library.setName(name);
    //cout << library.getName() << endl;

    cout << "Enter your surname: " << endl;
    cin >> surname;
    library.setSurname(surname);
    //cout << library.getSurname() << endl;

    cout << "Enter your LSP number: " << endl;
    cin >> LSP;
    library.setLSP(LSP);
    //cout << library.getLSP() << endl;
    //library.toString(name);

    library.setIfPersonAlreadyExists(IfPersonAlreadyExists);
    // cout << library.getIfPersonAlreadyExists() << endl;

    library.checkIfPersonAlreadyExists(IfPersonAlreadyExists, LSP);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it already returns a boolean...whats the question?

Comment: Don't use a parameter name that is the same as a member variable name. It's legal but it's confusing.

Comment: It should return boolean, but it does nothing and my question is: Is there a problem in my code that it doesn't return the answer?

Comment: @user3633116: you do nothing with returned value

Comment: shouldn't return IfPersonAlreadyExists print out true of false?

Answer (score 2):

In order to print `true` and `false` instead of `1` and `0` respectively use [`std::boolalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/boolalpha/) like the example below:

`std::cout << std::boolalpha << library.checkIfPersonAlreadyExists(IfPersonAlreadyExists, LSP) << std::endl`;

The member function `Library::checkIfPersonAlreadyExists` returns a `bool` already.

Edit:

Also include `string` header (i.e., `#include <string>`).

Comment: I used boolalpha. My function doesn't return bool type variable. And I don't know what's the problem..

Comment: I tested it and it run "fine" when I included the `string` header.

Answer (score 0):

cout << library.getIfPersonAlreadyExists() << endl;

Should return 0 or 1 I think.

Just do cout << (library.getIfPersonAlreadyExists() == true ? "true" : "false") << endl;

Comment: `std::boolalpha` exists so you don't need to do that

Answer (score 0):

You will get less confused if you use different Capitalization for locals, globals and parameters.

```
    void setIfPersonAlreadyExists (bool IfPersonAlreadyExists) {
        this -> IfPersonAlreadyExists = IfPersonAlreadyExists;
        IfPersonAlreadyExists = true;
    }
```

Its always true!